# View not showing up when an extension command is typed/selected

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a vscode client extension that needs to show

- Shows a webview on the Primary Sidebar (already works)
- Opens a view when a certain extension command is selected (it fails)

The package.json looks like this

```json
 "activationEvents": [
    "onView:navCode.search",
    "onLanguage:typescript",
    "onCommand:navCode.start"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/extension",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "navCode.start",
        "title": "Show class diagram",
        "category": "NavCode Diagram"
      }
    ],
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "nav-code-search",
          "title": "Nav Code",
          "icon": "images/nav-code-logo.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "views": {
      "nav-code-search": [
        {
          "type": "webview",
          "id": "navCode.search",
          "name": "Code search"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

The activate method of my extension looks like these

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    let refManager = new ReferenceManager();
    refManager.updateWorkspaceReferences();

    //Register the webview for code nav search
    const provider = new SearchViewProvider(context.extensionUri, context, refManager);

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(SearchViewProvider.viewType, provider)
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(// Create and show a new webview
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('navCode.start', () => {
            const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
                'navCode', // Identifies the type of the webview. Used internally
                'NavCode - Class Diagram', // Title of the panel displayed to the user
                vscode.ViewColumn.One, // Editor column to show the new webview panel in.
                {} // Webview options. More on these later.
            );
        })
    );
}
```

The command appears correctly

[image]

But when is selected it shows this error
[image]

There is nothing else on Console or Output views, what could be causing this ?

I have searched without any success about how to register multiple views of the same extension

**UPDATE**

But back to the problem I believe that is realted to this method
`refManager.updateWorkspaceReferences();`

Because it awaits until a typescript parses all the *.ts files of the current workspace

```js
public async updateWorkspaceReferences() {
    let message: string;
    let folders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;

    if (folders && folders.length > 0) {
        message = await this.processProject(folders[0]);
    }
    else {
        message = 'nav-code requires an open workspace to work';
    }
    this.log.append(message);
}
```

How can a have a running task, right after the extension is activated ? can I use threads ?

Comment: what if you put the `context.subscriptions.push` at the start of the activate, if activate terminates before that call it will never happen

Comment: I put it the registerCommand as high as possible and problem continues

Comment: have you set a breakpoint on the `register` call to see it it executes? What if you place a simple info message on the command?

Comment: the breakpoint is not being hit, logging to the outputchannel or console.log does not work either...what the h*ck ?

Comment: do you have typed `navCode.start` exact the same in all strings used

Comment: I have updated my question, I believe a long running task that is being awaited on the activation might be the cause.

Comment: Actually after packaging my extension with webpack seems that I have broken the ability to have breakpoints to be bound

Comment: create a `Promise`, let it do the background task and call a function in your main code to signal the task is finished

Comment: can webpack generate a `.map` file, just like the ts compiler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249228/discussion-between-mauricio-gracia-gutierrez-and-riov8).

Comment: @rioV8 - I have created this question regarding the debugging not working - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74281385/cant-debug-typescript-extension-vs-code-because-corresponding

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overview of what I ended up doing to solve the problem

1. Put the long-running logic inside the `SearchViewProvider` (not running directly inside the `activate` method but as a promise that notifies when done
2. `SearchViewProvider` gets notified by `ReferenceManager` that the long-running logic has finished using `BehaviorSubject` (rxjs) : `referencesUpdated`
3. The view is initialized with a default content when notified the content is refreshed.

Here is the relevant code

extension.ts

```js
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    
    //Register the webview for code nav search
    const provider = new SearchViewProvider(context, logger);

    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(SearchViewProvider.viewType, provider)
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(// Create and show a new webview
        vscode.commands.registerCommand('navCode.start', () => {
            const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(
                'navCode', // Identifies the type of the webview. Used internally
                'NavCode - Class Diagram', // Title of the panel displayed to the user
                vscode.ViewColumn.One, // Editor column to show the new webview panel in.
                {} // Webview options. More on these later.
            );
        })
    );
    
}
```

SearchViewProvider.ts

```js
constructor(
    private context: vscode.ExtensionContext,
    private logger: Logger
) { 
    this.extensionUri = this.context.extensionUri; 
    this.referenceManager = new ReferenceManager(logger);
    this.referenceManager.referencesUpdated.subscribe(() => { this.refreshView() });
}


public resolveWebviewView(webview: vscode.WebviewView, context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext<unknown>, token: vscode.CancellationToken): void | Thenable<void> {
    this.view = webview;

    if (this.view) {
        /** existing view logic **/
        this.refreshView();
    }
}

refreshView() {
    if (this.view) {
        this.view.webview.html = this.buildView(this.view.webview);
    }
}
```