# Can't debug typescript extension VS Code because it dit not found source file

Tags: visual-studio-code, webpack, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have been working on a vsCode extension and was able to launch and debug fine.

But now after bundling the extension with webpack I'm unable to bind breakpoints correctly

**Things that I have tried**

- Apply the solutions mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53236103/1461862
- Change the outFiles from /out/ to /dist/
- removing the outFiles configuration

The dist folder contains an extension.js.map but still vscode is unable to bind the breakpoints
but the problem continues

**The error I'm getting is:**

> We couldn't find a corresponding source location, and didn't find any
> source with the name extension.ts

[image]

Here are the relevant files

lauch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test/suite/index"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the webpack.config.js

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
    target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

    entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
    output: { // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json),  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'extension.js',
        libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
        devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: "../[resource-path]",
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
        vscode: "commonjs vscode" // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed,  -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
    },
    resolve: { // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files,  -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                options: {
                    compilerOptions: {
                        "module": "es6" // override `tsconfig.json` so that TypeScript emits native JavaScript modules.
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    },
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I also ran into this problem and can't find any solution.

Comment: No I have not, I ended using custom logging methods to output the status of my extension at any given time, a nightmare

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things that need to be in place for debugging to work after using webpack

- `launch.json` has to point to the correct directory for the output files (eg `dist`)
- `package.json` has to point to the correct directory for the `main` setting (eg `dist/extension.js`)
- `webpack.config.js` has the output directory (eg `dist`)
- VS Code runs the npm script "watch" before launching the debugger (this is the `"${defaultBuildTask}"` in launch.json. Ensure this script exists, and not the original script (`tsc`, which outputs files to `out/`, but `package.json` is pointing to `dist/`, that won't work).
- webpack must be run in development mode. If you have executed `vsce package`, files will exist in the `dist` directory, but they won't be in development mode. The debugger will launch the extension based on this, but you can't debug. So, you need an npm script like this in package.json: `"watch": "webpack --mode development"`. Note the `development` mode.

In all probability, you are missing the `watch` script. I faced the same problem as you, and adding the `watch` script solved it.

Note that although it is called `watch`, I have not added `--watch` to the webpack command line. This is because the default build task (see `tasks.json` under .vscode directory) defines the problem matcher as `$tsc-watch` which does not recognize when the webpack compilation is over.

If you really want the `watch` to work, you will need to install an extension [Typescript Webpack Problem Watcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amodio.tsl-problem-matcher) and change the problem matcher from `$tsc-watch` to `["$ts-webpack-watch"]`. Now, when you edit and save a file, it will be recompiled. But the extension won't be reloaded automatically with the new code. For that you have to press Cmd+R (Mac) or Ctrl+R (windows) in the Extension Development Host window. This is a few seconds faster than relaunching the debugger, which is what you will have to do without the `watch` task.

BTW, this is the extension I am working on https://github.com/agrostar/zzapi-vscode - check out the package.json and other files there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `outFiles` configuration in your `launch.json` file to match the output folder of your webpack bundle. In your case, it should be:

```json
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"
]
```

This will tell VSCode where to look for the source maps and the transpiled JavaScript files that correspond to your TypeScript files. The `devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate` option in your `webpack.config.js` file is also important, as it tells webpack how to generate the source map paths relative to your workspace folder.

The reason why you are getting the error `We couldn't find a corresponding source location, and didn't find any source with the name extension.ts` is because VSCode is looking for the source file in the `out` folder, which is not where webpack puts it. By changing the `outFiles` configuration, you are telling VSCode to look for the source file in the `dist` folder instead, where webpack has generated the source map and the transpiled JavaScript file.

To understand more about how VSCode debugs TypeScript files with webpack, you can read this article: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_webpack

I hope this answer helps you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already tried that and still does not work, is mentioned in my question

Comment: Also you mention `devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate` but dont mention how should I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that is worth trying, is to re-open visual studio directly in the folder that your project is contained within.

On windows (perhaps also mac), navigate to the folder where your project is located with a terminal and open code here with:

`code .`

Try your debugging tools again, and see whether or not you hit the break points this time.